# Changed the AllowOverride to All and still nothing

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I tried to write a .htaccess file on my local pc's website, 
I've realized I need to set AllowOverride All instead of None
searched, found the file /etc/apache2/conf.d/security
in the file I found

```
#<Directory />
#AllowOverride None
#Order Deny,Allow
#Deny from all
#</Directory>
```

changed it to

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

typed

```
service apache2 restart
```

and... .htaccess still didn't work :I

the file by the way, holds one line, deny from all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer from original poster:**

> Finally found the right place: /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
>   search for the
>
> ```
> <directory /var/www/>  part, and changed it to:
>
> <Directory /var/www/>
>     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>     AllowOverride All
>     Order allow,deny
>     allow from all
> </Directory>
> ```

Comment: Or alternatively, `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` (which just provides symlinks to `/sites-available`).