# How to hide php extension in url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

Am using 'xampp' in windows 7.
I have my index.php in a folder under the localhost(root) and the path would be like `(http://localhost/folder/index.php)`
And i added the below lines in the file '.htaccess' which i have placed under the folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index index.php [L]
```

But its not working.
Help me.

Comment: @Rikesh i tried its not working

Comment: Make sure you have `mod_rewrite` on at your server.

Comment: @Rikesh yeah its available

Comment: Make sure [allowoverride](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999442/changed-the-allowoverride-to-all-and-still-nothing?rq=1) is set to ALL

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

also enable Rewrite module

Comment: check your Rewrite module enable or not?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131236/how-do-you-enable-mod-rewrite

Comment: @Saini yeah its there

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: not working, where to place '.htaccess' file?

Comment: @sufi, it works, enable mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: not working, where to place '.htaccess' file?

Comment: 'RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index.php index [L]' This is working fine in [link](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/), but not working in browser.